# How to import the Angular 4 upgrade module in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm  performing an ng1 to ng2 upgrade. The ng1 app does not use any module system - dependencies are manually copied, while the ng2 app uses WebPack.

[The docs](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#bootstrapping-hybrid-applications) state to add this line to the SystemJS:

```
 '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js'
```

How else can I load the @angular/upgrade js into the ng1 app?

Comment: AngularJS can use webpack too: https://github.com/preboot/angularjs-webpack